# ArcMap 'Add Locations' field mappings not showing added field for network analyst layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, field-mapping, closest-facility

I have successfully created a new field 'Status' in the incidents sublayer of a closest-facility network analyst layer, using the 'Add Field to Analysis Layer' tool.
[image: created field]

However, when I try to populate the incidents layer with the 'Add Locations' tool, I can't seem to get the field to show up in the field mapping box.[image: field mapping box]

I've tried searching ESRI's webpages on the two tools but can't seem to find anything regarding how to populate the field other than in the field mapping area. How can I get the field to show up?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem 'Status' cannot be used as a custom field name for this analysis layer, as it is populated with other values and doesn't appear in the field mapping area. When using a differently-named field, it shows in the field mapping on the Add Locations tool.